# finding matching rows in matrix

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have an (m x n) matrix Q, and a row vector r, e.g.

```
Q = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 2 3 ; 5 6 7 ; 1 2 3 ; 1 2 3 ; 1 2 5 ];

r = [ 1 2 3 ];
```

What is the easiest way to obtain a logical vector (of length m) that indicates which of the rows in Q are identical (for all elements) to the specified row r?

In the sample case above, that should be

```
[ 1 0 0 1 1 0 ];
```

Comment: Very closely related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209904/find-given-row-in-a-matrix

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) and do it in a single line:

```
>> ismember(Q,r,'rows')'

ans =

     1     0     0     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 13):

```
all(bsxfun(@eq, r, Q),2)'
```

`bsxfun(@eq, r, Q)` compares each row and returns a matrix with same size as Q:

```
>> bsxfun(@eq, r, Q)

ans =

   1     1     1
   0     1     1
   0     0     0
   1     1     1
   1     1     1
   1     1     0
```

the `all` function computes if the result of bsxfun is all true along each row separately. Thus it returns:

```
>> all(ans,2)'

ans =

   1     0     0     1     1     0
```

and yeah, there is also a transpose operator `'` to match your desired row output

Comment: Worth noting that this is quite a bit faster than ismember

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1 1 1; 2 2 2; 3 3 3];
b = a(1:2,;);
[temp locb] = ismember(a,b,'rows');
b(locb(locb~=0),:)

ans =

     1     1     1
     2     2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier way with `repmat`:

```
a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
t = [4 5 6];
[x,y] = size(a);
r = all(a==repmat(t,y,1), 2)'
```

Comment: also less efficient and slower, see: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/#9

Comment: Efficiency where it is not needed is a curse. Simplicity to write and understand relates directly to better code.

Comment: what's so difficult to understand about `bsxfun(@eq, r, Q)`?? If you learn it with such easy examples, you benefit from it later when applying on complex problems..

Comment: Readability. You've just threw that out of the window. And to gain what? 0,01 second. Use arrayfun, spfun, cellfun, bsxfun when performance is really an issue. Otherwise, you'll be unnecessarily overcomplicating the code. Besides that, minus voting a right answer is downright juvenile.

Comment: if you know what bsxfun does, readability is not an issue at all; Every function has to be learned at some point.. By the way, in case that readability still is an issue, they invented something for that: comments. If I didn't know what repmat does, your code wouldn't make sense either

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183201/should-a-developer-aim-for-readability-or-performance-first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754/performance-vs-readability http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/43151/should-you-sacrifice-code-readability-with-how-efficient-code-is

Comment: I repeat myself: "If I didn't know what repmat does, your code wouldn't make sense either" Why is using `repmat` easier to understand?
In the [doc of repmat](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) , bsxfun is literally mentioned as a (sometimes) better alternative: "If you have code that uses repmat and also a binary operator or function, you can transform the code to use the bsxfun function instead. In certain cases, this can provide a simpler and faster solution."

Comment: I find `repmat` to be on a similar level of readability as `bsxfun` - it's the `ismember` solution that is much clearer.