# "with" and "no with" in template engines

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, template-engine, dot.js

I am on a search for a javascript template engine that has good performance when used in **large js applications** and is also very suitable for **mobile applications**. So I have gone through the various jsPerf-tests for these. There seems to be a lot which show different results and it is confusing to find out which is the standard test.

Can some one guide me a standard jsPerf that I can refer to and that should also include following templates dust, underscore, hogan, mustache, handlebars.

1. From what I have observed dot.js is a constant performer with good
   rendering speed, but is it mature enough for larger applications ?
2. What is "with" and "no with" (specific to **underscore.js**)that is shown in the jsPerf tests?
   Can some one explain.
3. In all the tests I have seen popular templates like mustache,
   handlebars, dust, hogan,etc seems to be behind performance than
   other templates, so why people are using them leaving out the top
   performers,is it because of maturity of these template engines?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mind listing the jsPerfs you went through for reference?

Comment: regarding question 2: »By default, template places the values from your data in the local scope via the with statement« from the docs. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Comment: Hi this is the perf test I have settled with..http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/473

Comment: @rodneyrehm I have come to know the differences between with and no with specific to underscore, but I do hav a question Is it always possible to implement underscore using no with, i mean incase of precompiling and caching...?

Comment: @bhargav I hate "with" so I set my underscore settings to globally use an object: `_.extend( _.templateSettings, { variable: "data" } );` Now I can compile / render templates without having to append `{ variable: "data" }` every time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can some one guide me a standard jsPerf that I can refer to and that
>   should also include following templates dust, underscore, hogan,
>   mustache, handlebars.

I know of non off hand. Is that required? Why?

### Underscore

> What is "with" and "no with" (specific to underscore.js) that is shown
>   in the jsPerf tests? Can some one explain.

#### With, Convenient, Slower performance

```
_.template("<%= myvar %>", { myvar: "foo" });
```

#### Non-with, Inconvenient, Faster performance

```
_.template("<%= data.myvar %>", { myvar: "foo" }, { variable: "data" });
```

#### Best of both worlds

```
_.extend( _.templateSettings, { variable: "data" } ); // Do this once.
_.template("<%= data.myvar %>", { myvar: "foo" });
_.template("<%= data %>", "foo");
_.template("<%= override.myvar %>", { myvar: "foo" }, { variable: "override" });
```

Also note that the template function returns a compiled template if the second argument is null, undefined, or not given. So in the case of the override variable:

```
var renderFn = _.template("<%= override.myvar %>", null, { variable: "override" });
renderFn({ myvar: "foo" });
```

### Performance vs Readability

> In all the tests I have seen popular templates like mustache,
>   handlebars, dust, hogan,etc seems to be behind performance than other
>   templates, so why people are using them leaving out the top
>   performers,is it because of maturity of these template engines?

Not everything in JavaScript is about performance. There has to be a balance between scalability, maintainability, readability, and convenience. The rule of thumb being code for readability and convenience then only optimize for performance where needed. There is an [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754/performance-vs-readability) that has a good discussion on the topic.

So to answer, other template methods are often chosen with performance at a lower priority then others.